# arithmetic commands in tcl/tk programming

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am programming in tcl\tk.
The code is showing following error:

```
"missing operand at _@_
in expression "+_@_""
```

```
entry .e1 -textvar a
entry .e2 -textvar b
message .m -textvar c
button .b -text "press here" -command "set c [expr $a+$b]"
```

The error is showing in the last line. I am running it in tclsh and showing the same error. I have also tried using it in function `proc` but the same error is popping up.
I am trying to do arithmetic operations using tk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the 4th line is evaluated by the interpreter it expands the contents of the quoted part and will execute the `expr` command with the contents of `a` and `b` expanded. However, these variables have no value at that point in time. You meant to evaluate that command when the user clicks the button but it is being evaluated when the button is created.

The quick fix is you need:

```
button .b -text "press here" -command {set c [expr {$a + $b}]}
```

provided `a` and `b` are global as the command will be evaluated in the global namespace when the button is clicked.

The longer fix is you need to read the [Tcl man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) quite carefully with attention to the description of the differences between quoted `""` and grouped `{}` expressions in Tcl.

Comment: An adjunct to that is _always_ brace your expressions and always create your callbacks as calls to procedures. Or rather the cases where you don't are so rare and so experts-only that it might as well be always; bracing things and using helper procedures works very well.

Comment: And if this is intended to take input from users, it might be a good idea to make sure that the variables a and b are numbers before doing the calculation.